# Accounting for Nulls/Convert into Spaces of 'x' length

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

```
SELECT
CONVERT(CHAR(10), Title)
+ CONVERT(CHAR(75), FirstName)
+ CONVERT(CHAR(75), LastName)
+ CONVERT(CHAR(100), EmailAddress)
FROM
AdventureWorks.Person.Contact
```

If a value is null, how would I accomodate that in this situation?

**My ultimate goal: create a fixed length output.**

*Ideally: if its a null value, make is white space of that length specified.*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this SQL Server, MySQL, ...?

Comment: It is SQL server 2008, Apologies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also use the CAST CHAR technique instead of padding string by replicate:

```
create table Person
(Firstname varchar(50) not null,
 Lastname varchar(50) not null,
 Email varchar(50));

insert into Person values
('John Winston','Lennon', 'jwl@beatles.com'),
('James Paul','McCartney', null),
('George','Harrison', 'g@beatles.com'),
('Ringo','Starr', 'rstarkey@beatles.com');


select 
Fullname = 
     CAST(Lastname, AS CHAR(50))
     + CAST(Firstname AS CHAR(50))
     + CAST(COALESCE(Email,'') AS CHAR(50)) 
from person
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb771/1

Note, SQL Fiddle don't have error nor the query above, it's just that browsers render multiple spaces into one, you can see it's 50 characters by using Inspect Element(if you are using Google Chrome) on the grid. The display has 50 characters on each CAST

Of course you can also use CONVERT http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb771/3

```
select 
    Fullname = 
        CONVERT(CHAR(50), Lastname)
        + CONVERT(CHAR(50), Firstname)
        + CONVERT(CHAR(50), COALESCE(Email,'')) 
from person
```

Of course you can also use ISNULL http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb771/4

```
select 
    Fullname = 
        CONVERT(CHAR(50), Lastname)
        + CONVERT(CHAR(50), Firstname)
        + CONVERT(CHAR(50), ISNULL(Email,'')) 
from person
```

Just to verify things are working as intended, visualize space:

```
with a as
(   
    select 
        Fullname = 
            CONVERT(CHAR(50), Lastname)
            + CONVERT(CHAR(50), Firstname)
            + CONVERT(CHAR(50), COALESCE(Email,''))  
    from person
) 
select replace(Fullname,' ','.') from a

Lennon............................................John.Winston......................................jwl@beatles.com...................................
McCartney.........................................James.Paul..........................................................................................
Harrison..........................................George............................................g@beatles.com.....................................
Starr.............................................Ringo.............................................rstarkey@beatles.com..............................
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb771/8

Another tip, any performance-killer, e.g. [unnecessary function call](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) should be avoided, to make your queries fast. In this case, if Firstname and Lastname rejects NULL on inputs, no need to put COALESCE or ISNULL around them, in this case, we just put COALESCE or ISNULL on Email

Comment: Excellent.  Thank you both for the help!

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  COALESCE( CONVERT(CHAR(10), Title),         REPLICATE(' ', 10)),
        COALESCE( CONVERT(CHAR(75), FirstName),     REPLICATE(' ', 75)),
        COALESCE( CONVERT(CHAR(75), LastName),      REPLICATE(' ', 75)),
        COALESCE( CONVERT(CHAR(100), EmailAddress), REPLICATE(' ', 100))
FROM    AdventureWorks.Person.Contact
```

What you're looking for is [`COALESCE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx) (and [`REPLICATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174383.aspx) to make your life easier)

Alternatively you can [`CONCAT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231515.aspx) and [`LEFT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177601.aspx) it:

```
SELECT LEFT(CONCAT( Title,        REPLICATE(' ',10) ), 10) AS Title,
       LEFT(CONCAT( FirstName,    REPLICATE(' ',75) ), 75) AS FirstName,
       LEFT(CONCAT( LastName,     REPLICATE(' ',75) ), 75) AS LastName,
       LEFT(CONCAT( EmailAddress, REPLICATE(' ',100) ), 100) AS FirstName
FROM   AdventureWorks.Person.Contact
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: 'REPEAT' is not a recognized built-in function name.  Not sure why?

    Select left(concat(Title, REPEAT(' ',10) ), 10 as Title from AdventureWorks.Person.Contact

Comment: Yea, sorry. `REPEAT` should be `REPLICATE`

Comment: There's no CONCAT in SQL Server, use `+` operator to concatenate strings

Comment: Ok.. :-) there's CONCAT in SQL Server, but you have to upgrade to 2012 in order to use it. And its CONCAT can take care of NULL, it automatically convert null string to empty string http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/14906/2

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I accomplish this is by using the ISNULL statment.  I will typically write out ISNULL(Field,'      ') or whatever value I would pass across for a null such as N/a.  This ISNULL command takes in a value and returns the second parameter if the value is null otherwise it returns the value of the first parameter.